# Why are vote buttons on Stack Exchange shown when they can't be used?

Tags: website-design, usability, stackexchange

I've often wondered why Stack Exchange has opted to keep the upvote/downvote buttons available for clicking on question/answers posted by the user. For instance:

[image]

Even though these buttons have no use for the user, why are they still placed on the post's left hand column? Moreover, the comments have no controls for flagging/+1'ing the user's *own* comment. What is the reason for this discrepancy? What benefit do the +1/-1 buttons provide to the user, even though they can't be used for anything?

Comment: The buttons also remain when you have voted, and the vote is locked until the post is edited.  But the buttons do *not* remain when a question is archived/locked but kept for historical reasons.

Comment: I just clicked back to this tab and reflexively tried to close the warning in the screenshot.  =(

Comment: @gerrit But, once you've voted on a question, the buttons tell you which way you voted so they do at least serve a purpose. The voting buttons on your own questions/answers serve no purpose at all.

Comment: and wow, I didn't expect a +50 for my first UX question. Thanks to everyone who +1'ed :)

Comment: @Izkata do you often try to vote for your own posts? :)

Comment: Related question: http://ux.stackexchange.com/q/16707/5618

Comment: @DavidRicherby: "serve no purpose at all" is a hard thesis to prove. I would say, and others have argued here, that the buttons aid discovery, letting users know that a feature is sometimes available, even if it's not enabled at the moment. You may not find that to be a worthwhile purpose, but it is a purpose.

Comment: Duplicate of http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/52137/why-does-stack-exchange-require-you-to-click-to-be-turned-down?noredirect=1#comment82316_52137

Comment: @Zlatko: I have a short memory, and regularly think "Oh that's an interesting question... and I like this answer!  +1" "You can't vote for your own post" "...Oh, did I write this?  I did!"

Comment: @LarsH Yes, "serve no purpose at all" is overstating it. However, the votes on questions of a user who only looks at their own questions convey zero information, so are of no benefit to the site -- we can take for granted that everyone thinks their own questions are good. Any user who looks at a question posted by any other user will be presented with the buttons in a context where they actually do something, so they'll discover them that way.

Comment: I have the same [question](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/20162/when-should-i-use-the-no-access-prompt-rather-than-just-hiding-the-button) with the same print-screen image (although it has the old yellow prompt) :)

Answer (score 145, accepted):

Have you ever spend 30 minutes searching for a user interface element or menu item that you knew must certainly be there, only to eventually learn that it had disappeared completely because you were in some state where it couldn't be used?

Imagine that you don't know that you can't vote for your own post, and you have decided to upvote your own post. Or imagine that you recently learned about upvoting, and you have decided to upvote all the good posts about pie that you see to help promote their visibility, and now you are looking at a post about pie which you wrote but which you forgot you wrote. In any case, you're looking for the UP button.

You might spend an inordinate amount of time looking for the upvote/downvote button; you might even go so far as to waste someone else's time by asking a technical support person (or posting in meta) saying "Where is the upvote button?"

It is in my opinion a good heuristic not to make things disappear completely simply because the current state of the world is such that that thing cannot be used right now. It is usually better to leave the button there, possibly in a visually different state, and allow the user to try to click it and then have an opportunity to teach them why it can't be used.

Comment: I feel yah, bro. (*cough* windows *cough*)

Comment: Ok then, but why dont you disable the button, ie grey it out? This way you dont have to click it to see that you cant click it.

Comment: @StevenPenny: because then you'd have exactly the same problem: people wonder why it's disabled, get annoyed, ask support questions, etc...

Comment: @MichaelBorgwardt do you even HTML bro? You can just the `title` attribute.

Comment: @StevenPenny: do you even UX bro? Why hide information where many users will not find it?

Comment: @StevenPenny: Agree, disabling it would be good UX, still showing the message of course when clicked. Problem is, graying out a gray button isn't the easiest thing and showing just the outline might not be clear.

Comment: @DavidMulder if http://reddit.com/r/news can do it, Id say we can too.

Comment: @StevenPenny: Then again, reddit has one of the worst UX's and UI's and honestly, there are two shades of arrows there and as a (semi) new user I have no clue why... nor as UI designers.

Comment: @DavidMulder this keeps new users like yourself from ruining the unique atmosphere that redditors have been keeping for themselves so meticulously

Comment: Any change to the appearance of the arrows (lighter grey, outlines, dotted lines, empty space, etc etc) would stand out as unusual to someone familiar with the site - drawing the user's attention towards something that does nothing, like a sign saying "See this, here? Don't look at it!"

Comment: StackOverflow has the ability to hide voting buttons in a few edge cases. It's not all black and white.

Answer (score 49):

I had answered this question before but unfortunately the person who asked the question got banned for some reason :)

The reason is twofold:

- **For design consistency**: The placement of the **two voting options is there for every question and answer and the design is maintained even for the questions\answers which you have written to ensure there is design consistency** so that users are not confused by its sudden disappearance. You also need to note that you can favorite your own question and if the voting buttons were hidden suddenly, the user who would  have used the voting buttons as the relational positioning to to find the favorite option might be confused. Here is an example of me favoriting my own question:

[image]

- **To inform users about the number of up-votes a question\answer has got** : While the system doesn't allow you to vote up your own question or answer, the presence of the voting buttons keeps you informed about how your question is faring and the number of up-votes you have got (and in some cases how many down-votes you have got too).

[image]

Now the question that arises is if it won't irk the user to find out he cannot up-vote or down-vote his question\answer. I think what Stack Exchange here is relying on is the [concept of accidental discovery](http://www.uxbooth.com/articles/5-ios-behaviors-your-users-probably-dont-know/) so that users discover the functionality by accident.

I believe another reason accidental discovery also works is because it saves the **design effort of making a specific set of buttons or indicators for the self questions and answers of the user**. Even if Stack Exchange did find a suitable alternative, **you will need find a way to communicating why the voting indicators look different for the question\answer the person has posted – which would lead to more confusion**)

Comment: +1 You may also want to comment on what happens if a user who is not logged in presses the button, like just happened to me. =)

Comment: @jpmc26 you got urged to log in, or if you're not here, to create an account? :)

Comment: I think this is also missing another important point. It will **show the non-logged in users what they are missing out**. As well as to the users with not enough reputation of what they'd be able to do with more reputation. So surely it'll help boosting the conversion ratio.

Comment: Yes, but questions can also be locked so that to prevent voting, period. In that case, the voting buttons go away and only the votes remain. Its not consistent in that regard.

Comment: @0A0D Yes, but I think he is on point, encouraging conversion. While the inconsistency with locked questions is IMHO somehow accounting to the "showing quality" thing.

Comment: @0A0D Actually, that is still consistent if you look at it this way: the voting buttons are visible as long as it is possible for someone to vote on the question. When absolutely no one can vote, they vanish. Debatable whether that's a good user experience, but it is a possible reasoning.

Comment: I do not understand the second reason. The number of upvotes and downvotes is shown by clicking the total number, not by doing anything with the buttons.

Answer (score 44):

I don't have a study for this, but in my script of HCI (Einführung in die Mensch Computer Interaktion, Universität Hagen/Introduction to Human-Computer-Interaction University of Hagen) I read, that the brain can memorize the place of static interface elements better than dynamic ones.

If the buttons are always there and don't change much (like the content does) it will result in less cognitive demand, over time, to look at the interface.

Comment: +1 Anyone here keep the Windows functionality where it only showed Program menu items that were recently used? What a horrible idea THAT was.

Comment: Most of the time I had the feeling, this algorithm was hiding stuff I needed on purpose, lol

Answer (score 21):

For first time users to the community, simply showing the vote count without the up/down voting buttons could lead to confusion as first time posters may not know what this number represents.

I feel it is beneficial to leave this voting buttons in place for the user on their own questions for this reason at least.

Comment: Yea, also new users may think that it is impossible to upvote their answer not only for them but for everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I think it's because they haven't considered the user interface issues. It's the same on StackOverflow. What the StackExchange/Overflow team probably *should* do is dim them if they can't be used - so it's obvious they can't be pressed.

I don't know their data model, so I have no idea if this would simple or difficult for them.

Comment: You should avoid giving an opinion as an answer.

Comment: I don't have anything against your giving an opinion as an answer, especially since you labeled it as such. However, I think you'll find that the UX issues on SO have been pretty thoroughly considered and debated. That's not to say their conclusions are all optimal... maybe they suffer from *too much* input.

Comment: @Nigel Nquande, Because StackExchange won't allow anyone to comment on a post until they've reached some magical number of mystery points, I had to provide my opinion as an answer.

Comment: @LarsH, I have to disagree with that; I don't believe the StackExchange team has really thought through their UX issues.

Comment: @LarsH What I was trying to say, but was rudely required to insert in another comment was this: au contraire - I think they either got stuck on a design or went with something that looked "good enough". As useful and interesting as StackExchange, et al, are, they're not aesthetically well designed or especially usable. Some things on this site are difficult and some are made harder by apparently random rules. Many of the editing rules, for example, are apparently designed to discourage interaction (the question that started this discussion being a good example). 5 mins to edit a comment? Wow

Comment: I don't make the rules, @Ian, merely follow them. It's your own tough luck if you haven't gained 50 reputation points yet and others shouldn't have to suffer for it.

Comment: @Ian, I didn't say the UX was aesthetically well designed or especially usable; I just said the issues were thoroughly considered and debated. See all the discussion at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/user-interface?sort=votes for example.

Comment: Gee, you're nice (end sarcasm), @NigelNquande.

Comment: There's no way I'm wading through that lot, @LarsH! :-o

Comment: I waded through some of them, @LarsH. To say that some of the conclusions are "not optimal" (to paraphrase) was very... Diplomatic* of you! :-)   *changed from "polite", but it was that, too.